# Animating one image on top of another in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I have been using matplotlib to animate some images, but I am now finding that I would like to add more information to these animation so I want to overlay a scatter plot indicating important features. Here is the code I have been using to generate my movies so far:

```
def make_animation(frames,path,name): 

    plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = u'/Users/~/anaconda3/bin/ffmpeg' #ffmpeg path    
    n_images=frames.shape[2] 
    assert (n_images>1)   
    figsize=(10,10)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=figsize)
    fig.tight_layout()
    fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, bottom=0, right=1, top=1, wspace=None, hspace=None)
    #lineR, = ax.plot(xaxis_data[0],R_data[0],'c-',label="resources")
    img = ax.imshow(frames[:,:,0], animated = True)   


    def updatefig(img_num): 

        #lineR.set_data(xaxis_data[img_num],R_data[img_num],'r-')

        img.set_data(frames[:,:,img_num])

        return [img]


    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig, np.arange(1, n_images), interval=50, blit=True)
    mywriter = animation.FFMpegWriter(fps = 20)
    #ani.save('mymovie.mp4',writer=mywriter)

    ani.save("/Users/~/output/"+ path + "/" + name + ".mp4",writer=mywriter)

    plt.close(fig)
```

I would like to add a scatter plot on top of each frame, like I could do with a regular plot like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
img = ax.imshow(frames[:,:,0])
img = ax.scatter(scatter_pts[0],scatter_pts[1],marker='+',c='r')
```

My first attempt at this looks like this:

```
def make_animation_scatter(frames,path,name,scatter): 

    plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = u'/Users/~/anaconda3/bin/ffmpeg' #ffmpeg path    
    n_images=frames.shape[2] 
    assert (n_images>1)   
    figsize=(10,10)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=figsize)
    fig.tight_layout()
    fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, bottom=0, right=1, top=1, wspace=None, hspace=None)
    #lineR, = ax.plot(xaxis_data[0],R_data[0],'c-',label="resources")
    img = ax.imshow(frames[:,:,0], animated = True)   
    img = ax.scatter(scatter[0],scatter[1],c='r',marker = '+')

    def updatefig(img_num): 

        #lineR.set_data(xaxis_data[img_num],R_data[img_num],'r-')

        img.set_data(frames[:,:,img_num])
        img = ax.scatter(scatter[0],scatter[1],c='r',marker = '+')
        return [img]


    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig, np.arange(1, n_images), interval=50, blit=True)
    mywriter = animation.FFMpegWriter(fps = 20)
    #ani.save('mymovie.mp4',writer=mywriter)

    ani.save("/Users/~/output/"+ path + "/" + name + ".mp4",writer=mywriter)

    plt.close(fig)
```

This produces a video without the scatter plot so I am wondering how to implement this properly.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean exactly?

Comment: It produces a video with just the frames and not the scatter plot. I have edited the question to be clearer, thanks for asking.

Comment: Does the answer below solve this problem? (If so, please accept it)

Comment: Yes, I hadn't had time to test it earlier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html) say that when `blit=True` is used you have to return an "iterable of artists" from the update function in order to redraw them. However, you are only returning `img`. Furthermore, you are overwriting `img` with the image and scatter object. What you want instead is to use a different name for the scatter like

```
img = ax.imshow(frames[:,:,0], animated = True)
sct = ax.scatter(scatter[0],scatter[1],c='r',marker = '+')
```

both will still be drawn on the same axis but now you have `img` and `sct` artists and then the update function would be

```
def updatefig(img_num, img, sct, ax):
    img.set_data(frames[:,:,img_num])
    sct = ax.scatter(scatter[0], scatter[1], c='r', marker='+')
    return [img, sct]
```